# PHP PEARパッケージマネージャのインストールについて

Tags: php

PEARパッケージマネージャをインストールしようとして以下の作業を行ったのですが、コマンドプロンプトから何も反応が返ってきません。
何が原因でしょうか？

1) http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar をダウンロードし、c:\php\pear へ配置
2) コマンドプロンプトを管理者権限で開き、
`cd c:\php\pear`
の後、 
`php go-pear.phar`
を実行

go-pear.pharをテキストエディタで開くと、末尾(?>タグの後)が文字化けしているのが気になりますが、、

**環境**
OS：Windows10 Home
PHPバージョン： PHP5.6.17
※PHPはXAMPPではなく、単体でインストールしました。
※PHP各ファイルはc:\php に有り、そこへの環境変数Pathは通してあります。

Comment: 解決いたしました！
php.iniの設定を色々いじっていたのですが、これを最初の状態に戻したところ、インストールすることができました。
php.iniのどこかの部分の設定がまずくてインストールできなかったようです

Answer (score 1):

解決いたしました！
php.iniの設定を色々いじっていたのですが、これを最初の状態に戻したところ、インストールすることができました。
php.iniのどこかの部分の設定がまずくてインストールできなかったようです